# How to impersonate Farm Administrator in server object model?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, impersonation, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-object-model

We are using SharePoint Foundation 2010. We are creating content database and site collection using server object model. We have more than 1000 users in SharePoint. As content database and site collection creation are administartive task, only farm administartor can do that. In our case any user should be able to create content database and site collection with farm administartor account. Can we use SPUser or Is there any other way to do this ? Can you please provide me any code or link through which I can resolve the above issue ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might need to use the [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivleges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx).  This will allow you to run the code as if you were the <strike>farm administrator</strike> the application pool identity account.  Be careful because it gives the user running the code <strike>full</strike> higher access, but it sounds like that is what you want.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite topSite = new SPSite("URL_OF_YOUR_SITE_COLLECTION"))
    {
       //Any code you run here would run with the permissions of the application pool identity
    }
});
```

Comment: This is factually wrong - RunWithElevatedPrivileges runs the code as the Application Pool Identity, which is is not the Farm Administator (unless your code is running within Central Administration).

Comment: You're right, I've edited the post with your corrections, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PeterJacoby You should probably correct the code comment , too :)

Comment: And that's fixed now too :)